# Access control - patients and doctors

Tags: couchdb, access-control

**Is it possible for me to port my design considering the structure when it comes to users and access control?**

I develop a solution where a patient can report some data related to himself several times every day, and this can be read by a doctor. The doctor can have access to more than one patient but can only view the data in form of reports and visualizations. Currently I am working in Symfony2 (php framework) but I want to use only CouchDB JavaScript front end.

I have briefly reviewed couchdb and installed it. I have noticed that there are admin users and readers. **Is it possible to tweak this for my use case?**

Comment: You should read this to see how closely it fits your needs: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Security_Features_Overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own answer, based on http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/PerDocumentAuthorization is that CouchDb does not provide the suited authorization system. Therefore, I will probably not use couchdb.

EDIT: I could make each patient have his own database, make him an admin and make the doctors users with read privileges to the DB. I could then not use views. Any thoughts on this?

http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/PerDocumentAuthorization